# How to recover input categorical symbols from scikit-learn predict_proba?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a list of words of the same length. I store the length in a variable `LENGTH`. The list of words is called `wordlist`. I want to predict the first letter given all the others.  However I am having problems at the final stage where I want to associate probabilities from `predict_proba` with letters.

This is my work so far:

My target vector is categorical and so are my features. In particular they can take values from the ASCII alphabet.  In order to perform classification I first transform everything into integers.  To do this I make two dictionaries, one that maps from letters to integers (alphabet_map) and one that maps from integers to letters (inv_alphabet_map).

```
alphabet = set()
for word in wordlist:
    alphabet = alphabet.union(set(word))
alphabet_size = len(alphabet)
alphabet_map = dict()
alphabet_stored = sorted(alphabet)
inv_alphabet_map = dict()
for i in range(alphabet_size):
    inv_alphabet_map[i] = alphabet_stored[i]
    alphabet_map[alphabet_stored[i]] = i
```

I then make X and y as follows:

```
def makeX_simple(words, alphabet_map):
    X = []
    for idx in range(len(words)):
        X.append(list(words[idx]))
    X = [ [ alphabet_map[letter] for letter in sublist ] for sublist in X ]
    X = np.array(X)
    return X

X = makeX_simple(wordlist, alphabet_map)
y = X[:,0]
X = np.delete(X, 0, axis = 1)
```

Now I can build the classifier:

```
model = HistGradientBoostingClassifier(categorical_features=range(LENGTH-1), verbose=2,learning_rate=0.02).fit(X,y)
```

I can then do the following as a test:

```
models[0].predict_proba(X[0].reshape(1, -1))[0]
```

But how can I tell which probabilities are associated with which letters from my original input?   Does predict_proba sort the target variables and do I need to make another map from the index in the output array to the letter in my original input?

One difficulty is that I need the mapping from letters to integers to be the same for X and y.

What is the right way to do all this?

Comment: Why not use `LabelEncoder()` on target data?

Comment: @Abhi_J If I do that, how can I find out which probabilities from predict_proba are associated with which letters  ?

Comment: I've added a sample code, I hope the explanation helps.

Answer (score 1):

To transform target labels you can use `LabelEncoder()`, to categorical features you can use `OrdinalEncoder()`

1. Use `OrdinalEncoder()` to transform features while training
2. Use `LabelEncoder()` to transform target values while training
3. After prediction get target labels from `LabelEncoder()` using `.classes_` and zip each *prediction-probability* list with list of *target-labels*. This will give you something like:

```
[[('TARGET_A', 0.1),('TARGET_B',0.5),('TARGET_C',0.4)], [('TARGET_A', 0.5),('TARGET_B',0.3),('TARGET_C',0.2)]]
```

3. use `dict()` to convert each probability list from `list` of `tuples` to a `dict`, for easier access to values, to get:

```
[{'TARGET_A': 0.1,'TARGET_B',0.5:'TARGET_C':0.4}, {'TARGET_A': 0.5),'TARGET_B':0.3,'TARGET_C':0.2}]
```

Here is a sample:

Code to train/fit:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
import joblib

# while training
X = # your_categorical_features
Y = # your_target_labels

ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder()
ordinal_encoder.fit(X)
x = ordinal_encoder.transform(X)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(Y)
y = label_encoder.transform(Y)

model = HistGradientBoostingClassifier(categorical_features=range(LENGTH-1), verbose=2,learning_rate=0.02).fit(x,y)
# save label_encoder object
joblib.dump(label_encoder, label_encoder_filename)
# save ordinal_encoder object
joblib.dump(ordinal_encoder, ordinal_encoder_filename)
```

Code to predict:

```
# later while predicting
import joblib

# load label_encoder object
label_encoder = joblib.load(label_encoder_filename)
# load ordinal_encoder object
ordinal_encoder = joblib.load(ordinal_encoder_filename)

X = # your values to predict
x = ordinal_encoder.transform(X)

predictions = model.predict(x)
prediction_pobas = model.predict_proba(x)
p_labels = label_encoder.inverse_transform(predictions)

proba_list = []
for idx in range(len(prediction_pobas)):
    proba_list.append(dict([*zip(label_encoder.classes_, prediction_pobas[idx])]))

# access prediction probability by
target_A_probability = proba_list[0]['target_A']

# To use predicted value to call predict_proba again encode using ordinal_encoder
X = # your new values to predict
x = ordinal_encoder.transform(X)
```

Comment: `predictions` doesn't seem to be defined in `label_encoder.inverse_transform(predictions)`.

Comment: did you use `.fit()` on `label_encoder` object you created like `label_encoder.fit(Y)`

Comment: Yes. I just meant the variable is not defined. `predictions` doesn't occur anywhere above the line `p_labels = label_encoder.inverse_transform(predictions)`. Did you miss a line out?  The variable `p_labels` is also not referred to after that line.  What is it meant to represent?

Comment: @Anush, Yes I'm sorry I've updated the answer

Comment: I just realised the problem. I need the encodings for y to be the same as the encodings for X

Comment: From the question` X` and `y` are integers, here we just mapped labels to integers using `LabelEncoder`. What is your output/error now? Also what values of y did  you fit to the encoder, integer values (ie `y = X[:,0]` after alphabet_map) or character literals?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Your method works perfectly for recovering the letters associated with the probabilities. However I also want to be able to be able to use predict_proba to predict a value to feed into a new call of predict_proba. To do that I need the integer that would be associated with the letter in the encoded X.  If this was the same as the integer in the encoded y it would be easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230164/discussion-between-abhi-j-and-anush).

Comment: I've updated  the answer to use `OrdinalEncoder` to transform features. Do tell me if it helps.

Comment: It is a module to easily save and load models, encoders etc. as files to use later, similar to pickle. I added it in case you are training and predicting separately.